# second fundamental theorem of calculus with improper integral

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

is there an equivalent of this theorem 
$\int_a^b f(x) dx=F(b)-F(a)$ for improper intergrals, maybe limits appear on the RHS ? If so, how to prove it ?

My intuition is that in $\int_a^b f(x) dx, a<x<b$ so maybe we will have $\int_a^b f(x) dx=\lim_{x\to b^-}F(b)-\lim_{x\to a^+}F(a)$

Thank you

Tom

Comment: Did you read [this Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral)? It answers your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, the improper integral is $$\int_a^b f(x) dx = \lim_{u\to b-} \lim_{l\to a+} \int_l^u f(x)dx$$
By the FTC,
$$\int_l^u f(x)dx = F(u) - F(l)$$ where $F' = f$.

So $$\begin{align}\int_a^b f(x) dx &= \lim_{u\to b-} \lim_{l\to a+} \int_l^u f(x)dx \\&= \lim_{u\to b-} \lim_{l\to a+}[F(u) - F(l)]\\&=\lim_{u\to b-} F(u) - \lim_{l\to a+}F(l)\end{align}$$